# Handling of Array in C and C#

Tags: c#, c

I tried to insert an element in an array and it failed with array index out of bounds

I tried in C# it failed it works fine in c

```
int[] LA = {1,3,5,7,8};
int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
int i = 0, j = n;   
n = n + 1;
while( j >= k) 
{
    LA[j+1] = LA[j];
    j = j - 1;
}
LA[k] = item;
```

but it works in c

```
int LA[] = {1,3,5,7,8};
int item = 10, k = 3, n = 5;
int i = 0, j = n;
n = n + 1;
while( j >= k) {
    printf("j+1 =%d",j+1);
    LA[j+1] = LA[j];
    j = j - 1;
}
```

Can someone please explain why this is? and what about other languages will it keep varying? Thanks.

Many answers say it doesn't work in c so i have uploaded an image 
[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/No3Xq.png)

Comment: In case of C# try using `List<T>`: `List<int> LA = ... LA.Insert(index, value);`

Comment: "_array index out of bounds_" means somewhere at some time your code tries to use an array index value that is out of bounds of the given array. I mean, "_array index out of bounds_" means an array index is out of bounds... With regard to inserting an element: Arrays are of fixed size, thus "inserting" an element into an array would either require removing/replacing another element in the array or recreating the array with a larger size. Or, use a collection type that is resizable (like `List<T>` suggested in the first comment)\

Comment: @DmitryBychenko in this case, the error is that he's reading from `LA[6]`, so using a `List<T>` won't help.

Comment: your edit is missing the point: you are mistaken - you may *think* that it is "working" in C; it isn't - you've done something very very wrong and so far it hasn't hurt you; that is all; it is not "working"

Comment: btw: I can "fix" the C# too, look! `int* LA = stackalloc int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };` - done! this will also "work" for the same reasons (meaning: it is equally broken) - the reasons here being: your C array isn't bound-checked (just like my C# pointer); you have then accessed memory *past* the end of the defined range - that might be unused memory, it could be something really important, it could be an invalid page; at that point: your code is just broken

Comment: @MarcGravell from his attitude, I suspect giving him that C# is a bad idea - he'll just use it as his "solution"

Comment: C# has fewer [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). This is something that makes C# easier; you get an error message now rather than a really hard to find bug weeks later.

Comment: @Marc Gravell So does it mean c in general is not bound-checked are is this some kind of a bug in the environment

Comment: @nevas C arrays (which, when indexed into, are essentially the same as pointer expressions) are indeed not bounds checked; this is a feature of the language and that concept; if you want a bounds-checked type : don't use raw arrays (/pointers)

Comment: @nevas: Array accesses in C are not bounds checked.  Attempting to access an array element outside the range of the array leads to *undefined behavior*, meaning there’s no requirement on the compiler or runtime environment to do anything in particular.  Your code may appear to work as intended, or it may corrupt other data, or it may crash outright.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Better.  I’ll delete my comment.

Comment: Change `int[] LA = {1,3,5,7,8};` to `int[] LA = {1,3,5,7,8,-1};` to have additional empty element at end of array. The same is necessary for C version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh no, this doesn't "work", that looks like pretty blatant out of bounds writing, and thus you're getting undefined behavior. You cannot dynamically grow an array in C, they are statically sized at the point of "creation".

Note that C doesn't say that doing undefined things will result in any particular measurable result[*], so it can appear to do the intended thing, but still be *completely broken*.

[*]: That is what "undefined" means: there *is* no definition of what is going to happen. Some people seem to interpret it as "we're going to get the error handler for triggering that thing they call 'undefined behavior'", but that is not true. Anything could happen, anything.

Comment: "Anything could happen, anything". Undefined does not mean *anything* can happen. There are a set of things that could possibly happen when you read outside the bounds of an array. Your computer turning into a rabbit is not one of them. :)

Comment: @MineR This is *writing*, not reading. Also, of course the computer can't start violating laws of physics all of a sudden, but the point is that the C standard doesn't limit what could happen. You can't reason about it, unless you know what code the compiler happened to generate for this case, and how the underlying machine acts when the actual instructions generated execute under these conditions.

Comment: OR WORSE.  U.B. means that it can work fine during decades and then fail, without any apparent reason.

Answer (score 2):

On the first iteration of the loop, `j = n = 5`. However you're reading from `LA[j]`, which is `LA[5]`. LA only 5 elements, so you can read from and write to `LA[0]` to `LA[4]`. You're then trying to write to `LA[6]`, which is even further beyond the bounds of the array!

Fix your algorithm - you're not allowed to read from or write to elements outside of the bounds of the array.

The reason this "works" in C is that C isn't checking whether you're reading or writing outside of the bounds of the array. You're actually reading some random value that's sitting in memory beyond the end of your array. Technically this is invoking undefined behaviour, and anything at all could happen.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of array you can insert item easily using C# `ArrayList` or `List` like:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     ArrayList LA = new ArrayList() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };
     Console.WriteLine("The Original array elements are:" + string.Join(",", LA.ToArray()));

     int item = 10, k = 3;
     LA.Insert(k, item);
     Console.WriteLine("The array elements after insertion:" + string.Join(",", LA.ToArray()));

     Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Dotnetfiddle : https://dotnetfiddle.net/ISzZPz

Comment: Please don't use ArrayList - it was outdated in C# 2, 13 years ago! Use a generic `List<T>`. Also note that your suggestion combined with his code still crashes.

Comment: No. It doesn't  crashes. I execute it in a console application and pest it here.

Comment: As in, if you try and use the OP's original algorithm - `LA[j+1] = LA[j];` etc - that will crash, because you're still doing an out-of-bounds array read. Your answer ignores this, by throwing away the OP's original algorithm and writing something else instead.

Comment: Very funny argument :) why you want to use `LA[j+1] = LA[j];` with ArrayList. ArrayList has its own function for insertion. Anyway my focus is on the solution of this problem using C# not the output. Because you can represent this output in too many ways in C#.

Comment: @canton7 Other thing is, why you discourage someone using `ArrayList`. According to the problem domain, if somebody needs using multiple type together like `string` and `int`, in that case he has to be use `ArrayList`. Because you can't use multiple type using `List`.

Comment: @Arif even in that case, it's recommended to use `List<object>`

Comment: @Arif The OP wants to use `LA[j+1] = LA[j];` - it's in his question. The OP does not want to do insertion, and nothing in his question indicates he wants to do insertion.

Comment: @canton7 you can't understand my point about multiple type. Using ArrayList you can do this `new ArrayList() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, "canton7", "Arif" };` . But you cant do it using `List`. In that case `object/dynamic` is very costly. Because you need extra execution to get appropriate data from `object`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188420/discussion-between-arif-and-canton7).